# BigQuery Python API - Not able to authenticate using user

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

I have a project owner permission on bigquery. And I able to create/delete/insert records into bigqquery table from UI.

However, when I am trying from Python, I am getting following error.

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.ListJobs",
          "service": "bigquery.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Following is my code

```py
def insert_data():

    client = bigquery.Client()

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
        skip_leading_rows=1,
    )

    uri = " gs://xxx/csv_files/csv_test.csv"
    table_id="xxx.Gaurang.csv_data"

    load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
    )  # Make an API request.

    load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
```

Answer (score 1):

You must authenticate when you use Google's libraries; [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) and `gcloud` authentication does not extend transparently to code using the libraries.

Google's documentation is comprehensive and an example is here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries

Generally code run as a Service Account; the Service Account provides an identity and -- with Google Cloud services -- IAM provides roles/permissions based access, see [BigQuery: access control with IAM](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control).

Google provides a mechanism called [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically) that facilitates running code as a Service Account.